# php - Cast double com number_format

Tags: php, linux

Ao executar:

```
 $number = 50/3;   
 var_dump(number_format($number, 2, '.', ''));
```

é retornado

```
string(5) "16.67"
```

entretanto preciso que este valor seja dado em tipo decimal, logo eu executo o cast para ***(double)***.

Entretanto, ao realizar o cast:

```
$num = (double)number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
var_dump($num);
```

o php me retorna:

```
float(16.666666666667)
```

Assim, ele desconsidera a formatação da função

> number_format

Lembrando que isso acontece no servidor de produção.
No servidor de desenvolvimento, esse cast (double) respeita o number_format.

Já repliquei os mesmos dados da produção no server de desenvolvimento, porém sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Versão do PHP em Produção: **PHP 7.2.15-1+0~20190209065041.16+jessie~1.gbp3ad8c0**

Versão do PHP em Desenvolvimento: **PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u1**

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Se tu não fizer o cast pra double depois do number_format o valor fica com o número certo de casas decimais em produção?

Comment: Sim. Fiz o teste em Produção: removi o cast para double e ele ficou com o número correto de casas decimais.

Comment: Cara realmente ta estranho isso ae, eu testei local e funciona normal, quem sabe tu tenta usar outra coisa em vez de number_format, isso aqui deveria trazer o mesmo resultado. var_dump((float) sprintf('%0.2f', $number));

Comment: Entendi. Sinceramente acredito ser algum bug na versão do PHP que estou usando em produção. Em Desenvolvimento(Debian 9) não enfrentamos este problema. Mas em Produção (Debian 8 Jessie) é a primeira vez que enfrento algo parecido. Qualquer coisa vamos migrar o sistema do servidor de produção para uma versão mais recente do Debian, ou atualizar o PHP

Comment: Testei nessa ambiente: PHP 7.2.15-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, e funcionou normal.

Comment: Mas outra coisa coisa que tu ainda pode tenta é usar round($number, 2).

Comment: Testei round($number, 2) e persiste.

Comment: ok, só mais uma coisa então, antes de chamar o number_format bota isso aqui, ini_set('precision', 2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após vários testes em outras distribuições Linux e até mesmo usando o XAMPP para Windows, pudemos constatar que não se trata de bug de programação, erro de lógica ou algo do tipo, mas sim de um BUG específico da versão

> **PHP 7.2.15-1+0~20190209065041.16+jessie~1.gbp3ad8c0**

instalada em ambiente `Debian 8 Jessie`. Chegamos à conclusão em nossa empresa que é necessário migrar nosso sistema para uma versão mais estável, como o `Debian 9 "Stretch"`, por exemplo.

Apesar de que essas casas decimais não afetam na totalidade o uso do sistema, pois em nossas bases de dados usamos o tipo `DECIMAL(9,2)`, o que limitaria a entrada de dados com mais de 2 casas decimais e o sistema possui tratamos FRONT-END, porém no BACK-END teríamos essa "deficiência".

Fica a dica e experiência para os próximos usuários

Answer (score 0):

A função `number_format()` aceita apenas `float`, se queres usar `double` faz tudo com o `double` antes de cortares para o nº de casas decimais que pretendes.

```
$number = 50/3;
//Fazer tudo o que queres com $number como double antes de passares para float.  
var_dump(number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', ''));
```

Comment: Não, number_format aceita string, int, double e float.

Comment: @fajuchem  http://php.net/number_format de acordo com a documentação o primeiro elemento tem que ser "float $number"

Comment: Sim, a documentação pede float, mas é uma prática comum passar os números em outros tipo como por exemplo string, não encontrei onde tem essa informação mas ele deve fazer um cast pra float internamente. Além disso tua solução propem em trocar o double para float que no final é a mesma coisa, como descrito [http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php](aqui).

Comment: Ambos são da ordem de números reais. Como disse no escopo principal da mensagem, isso acontece com a versão PHP 7.2.15-1+0~20190209065041.16+jessie~1.gbp3ad8c0 (Debian 8) - Já na versão PHP 7.0.33-0+deb9u1 (Debian 9) tudo ocorre naturalmente e como preciso

Comment: Mas se eu simplesmente fizer number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '') o retorno final de number_format é uma string e não um (double)